# Two simultaneous scroll views behaving weirdly

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement a design like Twitter homepage on iOS, which can be simplified to something like the following:

[image]

Both scroll views receive gesture through the `gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)` method, which works well.

My scrolling logic is the following:

```
private func parentScrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  if self.parentScrollViewLocked {
    scrollView.contentOffset.y = threshold
    self.childScrollViewLocked = false
    return
  }

  if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= threshold {
    scrollView.contentOffset.y = threshold
    self.parentScrollViewLocked = true
    self.childScrollViewLocked = false
  }
}

private func childScrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  if self.childScrollViewLocked {
    scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
  } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
    self.childScrollViewLocked = true
    self.parentScrollViewLocked = false
  }
}
```

This actually works pretty well. The only problem though is when scrolling down slowly (but still with deceleration), there's a good chance the scroll ends at the threshold, without transitioning from parent scrolling to child scrolling smoothly. When scrolling fast enough, it's pretty smooth and can continue just fine.

What's intriguing is that when scrolling back up, no matter how slow I scroll I don't have any problem at all. Every time it's a smooth transition.

It turns out that for some reason, the child scroll view come to a stop signaled by `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` at the threshold - much earlier than the parent view. But the parent view is locked beyond the threshold so it doesn't move, and the child scroll view has already finished, so the scrolling will end there. When scrolling back up both scroll views behave normally, so my logic handles it fine.

What may be wrong here? Any pointer appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It is generally not the best practice to embed a `UIScrollView` within another `UIScrollView`. What is the content of the inner `UIScrollView`? What may be more appropriate is a normal `UIView` with a height `NSLayoutConstraint` that adjusts to fit the size of the `UIView`'s content.

Comment: @DavidChopin I have a dynamic height header and the inner scroll view is actually multiple collection views embedded in a paginated horizontal scroll view like twitter. If I don't need to use multiple scroll views I surely won't :)

Comment: Anytime I have a `UIScrollView` whose elements have dynamic height, I set a height constraint for each element and a height constraint for the scroll view as a whole. I then adjust the individual subviews' height constraints to fit their individual content and adjust the `UIScrollView`'s height constraint to fit all of the subview heights. You'll have to consider whether this will work for your situation.

Comment: My layout is much more complicated than that. Trust me, I've considered all the options I have and done quite some research on this :) Thanks though @DavidChopin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered the answer.

Basically, `contentOffset = 0` is a magic number: at this value, the scroll view needs to pick up its velocity from 0 even if the gesture already has a velocity. Therefore, simply set the default offset to something like 1 will do:

```swift
private func childScrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  if self.childScrollViewLocked {
    scrollView.contentOffset.y = 1  // <- set it to 1 instead
  } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 1 {
    self.childScrollViewLocked = true
    self.parentScrollViewLocked = false
  }
}
```

For perfectionists, set a corresponding content inset can offset this artificial offset (whelp!).

Now the two scroll views can hand off scrolling smoothly.